# How can I write a Go test that writes to stdin?

Tags: unit-testing, go

Say that I have a simple application that reads lines from stdin and simply echoes it back to stdout. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        fmt.Print("> ")
        bytes, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
        if err == io.EOF {
            os.Exit(0)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(bytes))
    }
}
```

I would like to write a test case that writes to stdin and then compares the output to the input. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "testing"
)

func TestInput(t *testing.T) {
    subproc := exec.Command(os.Args[0])
    stdin, _ := subproc.StdinPipe()
    stdout, _ := subproc.StdoutPipe()
    defer stdin.Close()

    input := "abc\n"

    subproc.Start()
    io.WriteString(stdin, input)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(stdout)
    bytes, _, _ := reader.ReadLine()
    output := string(bytes)
    if input != output {
        t.Errorf("Wanted: %v, Got: %v", input, output)
    }
    subproc.Wait()
}
```

Running `go test -v` gives me the following:

```
=== RUN   TestInput
--- FAIL: TestInput (3.32s)
    echo_test.go:25: Wanted: abc
        , Got: --- FAIL: TestInput (3.32s)
FAIL
exit status 1
```

I'm obviously doing something incorrect here. How should I go about testing this type of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example that writes to stdin and reads from stdout. Note that it does not work because the output contains "> " at first. Still, you can modify it to suit your needs.

```
func TestInput(t *testing.T) {
    subproc := exec.Command("yourCmd")
    input := "abc\n"
    subproc.Stdin = strings.NewReader(input)
    output, _ := subproc.Output()

    if input != string(output) {
        t.Errorf("Wanted: %v, Got: %v", input, string(output))
    }
    subproc.Wait()
}
```

Comment: I've removed the "> " from my output and used your TestInput function. I get a series of approximately 100 repeating failures that look something like this:

=== RUN   TestInput
--- FAIL: TestInput (5.17s)
 echo_test.go:36: Wanted: abc
  , Got: --- FAIL: TestInput (5.15s)
   echo_test.go:36: Wanted: abc
    , Got: --- FAIL: TestInput (5.13s)
     echo_test.go:36: Wanted: abc

...and so on.

Comment: It works fine for me when removing the "> ". Have you provided the right command to run ?

Comment: Go creates a temporary directory where to run the tests. When I print os.Args[0] this is what I get: `/tmp/go-build208836783/command-line-arguments/_test/main.test`. You need to install your program first with `go install ./...` so it ends in your path, then running the associated command. My main file is elyk/main.go so the command I run is "elyk"

Comment: Yes.  So why would it not work with the binary built for the test run?

Comment: When running a `go test`, go creates a testing binary. It creates a main that runs all tests of the files using goroutines, and compile this. This is not the same as your program. More details on why the test binary is different than the one produced by `go install` here: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of doing everything in `main` with `stdin` and `stdout`, you can define a function that takes an `io.Reader` and an `io.Writer` as parameters and does whatever you want it to do. `main` could then call that function and your test function could test that function directly.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about this and I expect this is what I will have to do.  I just wondered if there were a way to directly access main's stdin/stdout.